# Collapse an element when expand another element only css

Tags: html, css, jsfiddle

I have asp.net site. By some reason, I can't use javascript in my code. I use this code for create a expansible table:

```css
html, body, form {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #F5F5F5;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #DCDCDC;
}

tr:hover
{
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
}
.toggle-box {
  display: none;
}

.toggle-box + label {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  background-color: #F1F8FF;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

.toggle-box + label:hover {
  background-color: #C5ECFF;
}

.toggle-box + label + div {
  display: none;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.toggle-box:checked + label + div {
  display: block;
}

.toggle-box + label:before {
  background-color: #66AEFF;
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  content: "+";
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 25px;
}

.toggle-box:checked + label:before {
  content: "\2212";
}
#matru {
  border: 0;
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div runat="server" id="sidebar" style="padding: 5px 0 0 5px;">
    <input class='toggle-box' id='header1' type='checkbox' /><label for='header1'>Nguyễn Văn Tư</label><div>
        <table style='text-align: left; width: 100%; vertical-align: middle;'>
            <tr>
                <td>Tên khách hàng</td>
                <td>Nguyễn Văn Tư</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Mã khách hàng</td>
                <td>PC06LL0191387</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sery công tơ</td>
                <td>14138734</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Chỉ số cũ</td>
                <td>194.000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Chỉ số mới</td>
                <td>196.60</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sản lượng mới</td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <input class='toggle-box' id='header2' type='checkbox' /><label for='header2'>ĐInh Thị Tha</label><div>
        <table style='text-align: left; width: 100%; vertical-align: middle;'>
            <tr>
                <td>Tên khách hàng</td>
                <td>ĐInh Thị Tha</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Mã khách hàng</td>
                <td>PC06LL0182038</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sery công tơ</td>
                <td>14140069</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Chỉ số cũ</td>
                <td>2050.000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Chỉ số mới</td>
                <td>2104.10</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sản lượng mới</td>
                <td>54</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <input class='toggle-box' id='header3' type='checkbox' /><label for='header3'>Nguyễn Văn Nhựt</label><div>
        <table style='text-align: left; width: 100%; vertical-align: middle;'>
            <tr>
                <td>Tên khách hàng</td>
                <td>Nguyễn Văn Nhựt</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Mã khách hàng</td>
                <td>PC06LL0190775</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sery công tơ</td>
                <td>14138746</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Chỉ số cũ</td>
                <td>2699.000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Chỉ số mới</td>
                <td>2785.10</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sản lượng mới</td>
                <td>86</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <input class='toggle-box' id='header4' type='checkbox' /><label for='header4'>Mai Văn Lý</label><div>
        <table style='text-align: left; width: 100%; vertical-align: middle;'>
            <tr>
                <td>Tên khách hàng</td>
                <td>Mai Văn Lý</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Mã khách hàng</td>
                <td>PC06LL0182035</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sery công tơ</td>
                <td>14138744</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Chỉ số cũ</td>
                <td>2581.000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Chỉ số mới</td>
                <td>2631.70</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sản lượng mới</td>
                <td>50</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Full code here: https://jsfiddle.net/pdhung197/3eomjp3m/
But I want more: When I click on an collapsed element, that element will be expanded and other element will be collapsed.

This project can use only **CSS**, no **JavaScript** so I have no solution to do it.

Comment: This jsfiddle with inline css and unreadable html is no good. Please provide a jsfiddle which reproduces your problem and is readable. Personally I would use something like this: http://webdesignerhut.com/create-pure-css-tabs/.

Comment: can you please tell me how you open that div?

Comment: @HarshSanghani : That div is a sidebar and fix position at left of body.

Comment: you can take input as radio button instead of checkbox.

Comment: I saw the answer. Thank so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is simple. Just replace the input from `checkbox` to `radio` and add attribute `name`  with same value in all of the `inputs`.

This changes mean that there is just one input that can be `checked` in the same time. So, if you click to one item all the rest will be closed.

```css
html, body, form {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #F5F5F5;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #DCDCDC;
}

tr:hover
{
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
}
.toggle-box {
  display: none;
}

[type="reset"] {
  border: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: inherit;
  padding: 0;
  font: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  outline:0 !important;
}

.toggle-box + label,
[type="reset"]{
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  background-color: #F1F8FF;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

.toggle-box + label:hover {
  background-color: #C5ECFF;
}

.toggle-box + label + button {
  display:none;
}

.toggle-box:checked + label {
  display:none;
}

.toggle-box:checked + label + button {
  display:block;
}

.toggle-box + label + button + div {
  display: none;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.toggle-box:checked + label + button + div {
  display: block;
}

.toggle-box + label:before,
[type="reset"]:before{
  background-color: #66AEFF;
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  content: "+";
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 25px;
}

.toggle-box:checked + label:before {
  content: "\2212";
}
#matru {
  border: 0;
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 300px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div runat="server" id="sidebar" style="padding: 5px 0 0 5px;">
    <input class='toggle-box' id='header1' type="radio" name="radio" /><label for='header1'>Nguyễn Văn Tư</label>
    <button type="reset">Nguyễn Văn Tư</button>
    <div>
      <table style='text-align: left; width: 100%; vertical-align: middle;'>
        <tr>
          <td>Tên khách hàng</td>
          <td>Nguyễn Văn Tư</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Mã khách hàng</td>
          <td>PC06LL0191387</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sery công tơ</td>
          <td>14138734</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Chỉ số cũ</td>
          <td>194.000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Chỉ số mới</td>
          <td>196.60</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sản lượng mới</td>
          <td>2</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <input class='toggle-box' id='header2' type='radio' name="radio" /><label for='header2'>ĐInh Thị Tha</label>
    <button type="reset">ĐInh Thị Tha</button>
    <div>
      <table style='text-align: left; width: 100%; vertical-align: middle;'>
        <tr>
          <td>Tên khách hàng</td>
          <td>ĐInh Thị Tha</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Mã khách hàng</td>
          <td>PC06LL0182038</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sery công tơ</td>
          <td>14140069</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Chỉ số cũ</td>
          <td>2050.000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Chỉ số mới</td>
          <td>2104.10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sản lượng mới</td>
          <td>54</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <input class='toggle-box' id='header3' type='radio' name="radio" /><label for='header3'>Nguyễn Văn Nhựt</label>
    <button type="reset">Nguyễn Văn Nhựt</button>
    <div>
      <table style='text-align: left; width: 100%; vertical-align: middle;'>
        <tr>
          <td>Tên khách hàng</td>
          <td>Nguyễn Văn Nhựt</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Mã khách hàng</td>
          <td>PC06LL0190775</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sery công tơ</td>
          <td>14138746</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Chỉ số cũ</td>
          <td>2699.000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Chỉ số mới</td>
          <td>2785.10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sản lượng mới</td>
          <td>86</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <input class='toggle-box' id='header4' type='radio' name="radio" /><label for='header4'>Mai Văn Lý</label>
    <button type="reset">Mai Văn Lý</button>
    <div>
      <table style='text-align: left; width: 100%; vertical-align: middle;'>
        <tr>
          <td>Tên khách hàng</td>
          <td>Mai Văn Lý</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Mã khách hàng</td>
          <td>PC06LL0182035</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sery công tơ</td>
          <td>14138744</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Chỉ số cũ</td>
          <td>2581.000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Chỉ số mới</td>
          <td>2631.70</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sản lượng mới</td>
          <td>50</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

http://jsbin.com/pefobi

**Note:** If you need that the second click will close the tab again, you have to wrap all with `form` tag.

Comment: You saved me. Thank so much !

Comment: Nice solution but there is one issue. You can not collapsed with same click.

Comment: @ketan Although _Đồng Vọng_ didn't ask for it your challenge accepted ;) I was updated my answer.

Comment: @MoshFeu Nice one. :)

Comment: I didn't see that issue before ^_^ . Now I think I'm happy with this solution. Thank you Mosh Feu ;)